# How to adjust the position of labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to adjust the position of the upper Y-axis lables as shown below

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhMP2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move `xAxis.labels` at the top of the chart, you need to set `xAxis.opposite` to `true`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zh1L5djk/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite

Comment: can i change the color of them according to the corresponding column ?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that using `labels.formatter()` . Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ws6hg7jd/ API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter